# Excel Formula that will Sum the Count of a column excluding duplicates while meeting other criteria

Tags: excel-formula

The goal is to count the unique bill_ref's with the three criteria found below. I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried many other formulas.

The formula I used was the following:

```
=SUM(IF((SUM(--(FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A)>0))),COUNTIFS(D:D,">10",C:C{"Invoice","NULL","Cancel"})))
```

I was given a total of 14 "distinct" bill_refs. However, the correct count is 13 that meet the criteria of [enter image description here][1]

1. Being distinct bill_refs
2. Being either Invoice, Cancel, or NULL
3. Being > 10 "days_to_release"

See image for display of the table used. I apologize, this is the first time I've used stackoverflow.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE6Fj.jpg

Comment: I'm not clear on your rules. In the example data you have 15 line items. You exclude `bill_ref=7469` because the rule for `days_to_release` is not met. Now do you want to exclude only one or both of `bill_ref=6921`? Excluding both would get you to 12 line items, not 13. What happens if you have a duplicated `bill_ref` value and some of the duplicates meet the rule for `days_to_release` but others don't? E.g. what if for `bill_ref=6921` you had `days_to_release` of 8 and 31?